# Using MADAM with SSL

Tags: c#, security

I have been using Madam ([link](http://www.raboof.com/Projects/Madam/)) to provide Basic HTTP Authentication for some pages on intranet sites and want to use it to provide Basic HTTP Authentication on a public facing site with SSL.

While testing this out with the `DatabaseUserSecurityAuthority`, I was unable to get pages to authenticate. The pages would prompt for the credentials, but only returned access denied messages. I dug into the code and added some logging to find what the Authentication Header was returning and have found it to be blank!

Does anyone know how to get the Authentication Header on a Request on a Server using SSL in a HTTP Module?

Comment: I eventually traced the problem to the web.config file. In order to properly use the MADAM modules, they must be referenced in the system.webServer/modules tag in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually traced the problem to the web.config file. In order to properly use the MADAM modules, they must be referenced in the system.webServer/modules tag in the web.config.